# Using namespaceSelector

Tags: kubernetes

I have a `ValidatingAdmissionWebhook` with `namespaceSelector` and `objectSelector`, in addition to `configmap`.

Im trying to trigger the ValidatingAdmissionWebhook when the configmap 'UPDATE'.

This is part of the `ValidatingAdmissionWebhook`:

```
webhooks:
- name: myWebhook      
  ***
  namespaceSelector:
    matchLabels:
      namespace-label: namespace
  objectSelector:
    matchLabels:
      object-label: object
  rules:
   - operations: ['UPDATE']
     apiGroups: ***
     apiVersion: ***
     resources: ['configmaps']
```

This is part of the `configmap`:

```
data:
  data1: 'somedata'
metadata:
  name: myConfigmap
  namespace: test
  labels:
    object-label: object
```

When I remove the `namespaceSelector` from the ValidatingAdmissionWebhook, it catches the `UPDATE` from configmap, which is ok.

But I cant figure out how\where to add a namespaceSelector to configmap in order to be caught.

Tried to put it as part of the labels, but with no success:

```
data:
  data1: 'somedata'
metadata:
  name: myConfigmap
  namespace: test
  labels:
    object-label: object
    namespace-label: namespace   <----
```

If the `namespaceSelector` is a `labelSelector` kind, im not sure how to use it.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 2):

According to the K8s [documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/extensible-admission-controllers/), this is how Namespace Selectors work:

> The namespaceSelector decides whether to run the webhook on a request
> for a namespaced resource (or a Namespace object), based on whether
> the namespace's labels match the selector.

For your example to work, make sure to label the namespace your Config Map belongs to with `namespace-label: namespace`